# How to hide header element using react-native-webview

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-webview

I want to hide the header element from webview. I have written code as below, but i am not able to hide the header bar from webview. I am using **react-native-webview** library to implement this.
Can someone help me with this.
Thank you in Advance.

```
const jsCode = `
  let selector = document.querySelector("header");
  selector.style.display = "none"
  true; 
`;

return (
  <WebView
    source={{
      uri: 'url',
    }}
    onMessage={(event) => {}}
    startInLoadingState={true}
    injectedJavaScript={jsCode}
  />
);
```

Comment: How you're rendering the WebView component using react-native-webview or any props you're using, such as source, injectedJavaScript, or others ?

Comment: I have just return WebView component . i am able to see the webPage in my app. but not able to hide header. for that i have used injectedJavascript. but no luck . you can check my code

Comment: What about using `document.getElementById` instead of  `document.querySelector`?

Comment: i want to access classname of div

Comment: Please share the url.

Answer (score 0):

Try using,  **CSS Injection (consider browser compatibility)**:
Inject CSS code to hide the header element using injectedJavaScript or other methods.

**Example**:

```js
const injectedJavaScript = `
  const style = document.createElement('style');
  style.innerHTML = `
    #header-id {
      display: none;
    }
  `;
  document.head.appendChild(style);
`;
```